# Communication between electron js app and esp32 over network

Tags: esp32

I need to do windows app (most probably will be in electron js - not sure if is relevant) which will comunicate with an esp32 over the wifi network. Which protocol should I use for best performance and stability in communication between app and esp32? What you reccomend based on your experience? There will be a communication like Q/A - app send a command then wayt for a response and so on.

Thank you very much